# Self-Executing function passing arguments to external function

Tags: javascript

I am seeing some results in javascript while using globally defined functions mixed with self-executing anonymous functions which I don't understand. Here is the code:

```
var outerFunc = function(obj) {
    console.log(obj);
}

(function() {
    outerFunc({name: "my object"});
})();
```

The result here is that the following gets logged to the console as a string:

```
function () {
    outerFunc({name: "my object"});
}
```

Placing the "outerFunc" inside the other function's scope will log the object to the console just fine, of course.

Can someone explain to me why this functions this way? I suspect it has to do with closures and variables going out of scope, but I'm not positive.

Comment: [Here's a good article](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/) about why Immediatly-Invoked Function Expression IIFE is a more appropriate term than self-execution function.

Comment: Thank you, I was wondering what the correct term was for this type of function was. A quick google search confirmed I wasn't the only one to call them self-executing, but I'll use IIFE now that I know the correct term.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot to close the variable statement, and that's why it's not working

```
var outerFunc = function(obj) {
    console.log(obj);
}; // semicolon needed

(function() {
    outerFunc({name: "my object"});
})();
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Jwpp4/)

semicolons aren't always optional, and in this case it's parsed as

```
var outerFunc = function(obj) {
    console.log(obj);
}(
    function() {
        outerFunc({name: "my object"});
    }()
);
```

or more readable

```
var outerFunc = function(obj) {
    console.log(obj);
}(function_goes_here_passed_as_argument);
```

so it's no longer an IIFE, but a function passed as an argument, which ends up as `obj` in the other end, and is why the function is logged as a string.

Comment: Works great. Thank you for pointing that out, including a description of how javascript actually parses the item. Makes sense, and very helpful! I'll accept as an answer as soon as I am able.